# Having trouble in verifying the PACT from provider side using java junit5 maven spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit5, pact

I have to do PACT verification in java + spring-boot + maven.
I am currently running this tests with junit5.

My pom.xml looks like

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pactDirectory>${basedir}/target/pacts</pactDirectory>
                    <pactBrokerUrl><BROKERURL></pactBrokerUrl>
                    <projectVersion><PROJECTVERSION></projectVersion>
                    <trimSnapshot>true</trimSnapshot>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Consumer side code is runnning perfectly and published on pact broker too, here is the snippet of it.

```
package com.contract;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.notNullValue;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.testng.Assert;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslWithProvider;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactTestFor;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.RequestResponsePact;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.annotations.Pact;


@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)

class ContractTest {

    public static final String jwt_token = "Bearer eyJraWQiOiIyZjFiNzlmMS0xMDQ2LTQ2NGYtYjM5YS0xOGY4MDg5ZGMyMzIiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3RlbmFudDE1LWFkZW1hdHJpeHN0YWNrNC10cmlhbC5kc21sYWIuYm1jLmNvbSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IjVmNDU4ZjBlLWZmMzAtNDQ2ZC04ZTQwLWYzNjBlNjgyZjYyNSIsInRlbmFudCI6InN0YWNrNHRlbmFudDYiLCJqdGkiOiI4NDc3MDBhNC1hYWY0LTQ2NWMtYmNhYi05MDM0MzYxOTY0MDIiLCJzdWIiOiJEZW1vIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hZGVpdHNtMi1yc3NvLmRzbWxhYi5ibWMuY29tL3Jzc28iLCJpYXQiOjE2MjY3Njg0MjQsImV4cCI6MTYyNjc2OTMyNH0.EoXpqiyo5nvdPeYHfqq0sa15dQKYayD60UEboPVJojuYBKmvvj2yU03e61wy9Fkq2pZdoTNTifAeLDiG0dYKdlYOI5YTx_K6HGMav6ofYeOwIUj4OBVu7NyWxXVQz-3aXoIyu-MifUtvs6oQwf2YZmOEVtbPuCBxa9C9yA4i72g1TD31Rba1-e5cGG5ipiIE7UaunJ2K-mkt-BL2kzmu6OHdIP6vly7iTzxfOccdrjXEmedgX2hpnPcL_2os5wHCLwdHJwuYLPlgqDbSLHgpXdGL43Jg4ASBbFHg3h30y1yXYJazlgOwvVeBoOVcQYnXBh7wHTMik7zVMAo1VL8N_Q";
    
    public static final String API_V1_VIEW_ALGORITHM = "/aif/api/v1.0/algorithm/b82d4617-c39f-448b-bdf8-3fd52e3250ba";
    
    public static final String BODY_GET_VIEW_ALGO_V1 = "{\"tenantId\":\"6881408\",\"id\":\"5bc098db-7acb-4361-86a9-3c439b477142\",\"name\":\"New Job\",\"description\":\"New Job\",\"creationTime\":\"1625054173273\",\"template\":\"\",\"modifiedTime\":\"1625054173273\",\"owner\":\"ppan\",\"enable\":\"true\",\"executionMode\":\"onDemand\",\"definition\":\"\"}";
    
    private final static Map<String, String> headers;
    static {
        headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("Authorization", jwt_token);
        headers.put("authtype", "rsso-jwt");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(MockServer mockServer) {
        assertThat(mockServer, is(notNullValue()));
    }
    
    /* ----------------------------------Pact methods ----------------------------------------------------*/

    @Pact(provider = <provider name> , consumer = <consumer name>)
    public RequestResponsePact createPactViewAlgoV1(PactDslWithProvider builder) {

        return builder
                .given("algorithm id")
                .uponReceiving("a request with details of Algorithm")
                .path(API_V1_VIEW_ALGORITHM)
                    .method("GET")
                    .headers(headers)
                .willRespondWith()
                    .status(200)
                    .body(BODY_GET_VIEW_ALGO_V1)
                .toPact();
    }
    
    
    /* ----------------------------------Test methods ----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "createPactViewAlgoV1")
    public void testTokenRequest(MockServer mockServer) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = Request.Get(mockServer.getUrl() + API_V1_VIEW_ALGORITHM)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", headers.get("Content-Type"))
                .addHeader("Authorization",headers.get("Authorization"))
                .addHeader("authtype", headers.get("authtype"))
                .execute()
                .returnResponse();
        assertEquals(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), 200);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
        AIFAlgorithmModelNew actualResult = objectMapper.readValue(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), AIFAlgorithmModelNew.class);
        assertEquals(actualResult.getTenantId().toString(), "6881408");
        assertEquals(actualResult.getExecutionMode().toString(), "onDemand");
        assertEquals(actualResult.getEnable().toString(), "true");
        assertEquals(actualResult.getName().toString(), "New Job");
    }
}
```

I have written my Pact provider test class with standard pact format.
I am currently trying to run this on port: 8091.
Tried with port 9362 as well.
looks like this

```
package com.aif.api.contract;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

<Code libraries>

import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.State;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactBroker;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.HttpTestTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.HttpsTestTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationContext;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider;

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Cookie;
import io.restassured.config.SSLConfig;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestTemplate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = main.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-contract-test.properties")
@Provider("Provider")
@PactBroker(
        host="${PACTBROKER_HOST:PACTBroker URL}",
        port="${PACTBROKER_PORT:9292}"
        )
public class BasicTest {
    
    static {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "./conf/server_key.p12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "Y2hhbmdlaXQ=");
        }
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    
    @MockBean
    Algor
    
    @MockBean
    AlgorithmResource algorithmResource;
    
    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int serverPort;
    
    @Value("${pact.provider.version}")
    private String version;
    
    @Value("${pact.verifier.publishResults}")
    private String publishResults;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setupTestTarget(PactVerificationContext context) {
        System.out.println("Inside setupTestTarget");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", serverPort, "/"));
        System.setProperty("pact.provider.version", version);
        System.setProperty("pact.verifier.publishResults", publishResults);   
    }
    
    @TestTemplate
      @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
      void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest request) {
        context.verifyInteraction();
      }
    
    /* consumer = <Consumer Name> */
    @State("algorithm id")
    public void getAlgorithmById() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside getAlgorithmById");
        AlgorithmResponseTOFull responseTO = new AlgorithmResponseTOFull();
        responseTO.setTenantId("6881408");
        responseTO.setId("5bc098db-7acb-4361-86a9-3c439b477142");
        responseTO.setName("New Job");
        responseTO.setDefinition("");
        responseTO.setDescription("New Job");
        responseTO.setCreationTime("1625054173273");
        responseTO.setModifiedTime("1625054173273");
        responseTO.setOwner("ppans");
        responseTO.setEnable("true");
        responseTO.setExecutionMode("onDemand");
        responseTO.setTemplate(getAlgorithmTemplateResponseTO());
        
        Response response = Response.ok(Util.buildResponse(responseTO, Constant.STATUS_MSG_SUCCESS)).build();
        
        when(algorithmResource.getById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(response);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get error like

```
Verifying a pact between <consumer name> and <provider name>
  [Using Pact Broker PACTBROKERURL:9292]
  Given algorithm id
  a request with details of Algorithm
Inside pactVerificationTestTemplate
    returns a response which
      has status code 200 (FAILED)
      has a matching body (FAILED)

Failures:

0) Verifying a pact between <consumer name> and <provider name> - a request with details of Algorithm returns a response which has statusResult code 200
      expected status of 200 but was 401

1) Verifying a pact between <consumer name> and <provider name> - a request with details of Algorithm returns a response which has a matching body
      Expected a response type of 'application/json' but the actual type was 'text/html'
```

Please help me to resolve this, as I am getting above error and not able to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

In the consumer where the test is written , it is expecting a response of 200 and response type of "application/json".
If possible, please share the consumer test also that you have written.
Please check that  the pact which is getting generated at the **pact broker url**, and also what is the response and response type it is expecting.

Comment: Yes, @Gurkirat.
Consumer side is working fine. It has generated pact and published too on pact broker URL.
Yes it is expecting a status code of 200 and json response.
for reference, I have added consumer side pact code too, which is working fine.

Comment: @HimSinghvi it means that the response which you are sending from the provider side is not matching the case of status code 200 but rather giving invalid authentication ( status code 401 )  , I would suggest to look into that , that the responseTO set up is matching the status ok part. you need to set the headers also for the response that you are sending

Answer (score 0):

A 401 indicates the request contained invalid or no credentials.

Given that your consumer test has a JWT in it, my guess is that it's expired by the time the provider test runs.

See https://docs.pact.io/provider/handling_auth/ for strategies in dealing with this and the workshops here to see how to out them into action: https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/workshops/

Comment: I debugged. method in PactVerificationContext.class which is 
validateTestExecution(client, request, failures, testContext.executionContext ?: emptyMap())
request has auth headers and url. Still it failed. 
What could be the reason of failing as, when I pass actual running tenant id and other info while setting up the HttpTestTarget, then it runs and fetch the actual api response and it fails on body validation. So I am suspecting if it is related to running the service on localhost:<port>. When I checked that port status that was in listening mode only not established.

Comment: Are the auth headers valid? My point is that the JWT may have expired, so even if the auth headers come through they will be rejected by your service if they are expired. If you can debug into the Pact framework, can you debug into the part of your system that does the auth?

Comment: But for pact we mock all things and jwt also should be mocked, right?
If we need to provide live jwt then how will the test classes will run with CI/CD ?
Do I suppose to give live jwt every time?

Comment: Is there any way I can mock/pass jwt token along with my test cases?

Comment: Sure, but Pact doesn't know how to mock your code - you need to do that. Did you read the articles I linked above and the workshop that shows how to deal with it in java? The answer is in there, and the workshop has an example for this exact scenario.

Comment: I read few of the articles already and few now.
but I could not find any relevant example there. There is one example here in 
https://github.com/pactflow/example-provider-springboot/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/springboot/ProductsPactTest.java

But there is no mention of mocking any jwt token for service. There is mocking but for PACT broker server.
Can you please share which code you are talking about ?

Comment: I tried one more thing yday,
I commented "spring-boot-starter-security" from pom and ran the pact provider test class again. Now I am getting 404 error instead of 401.

Comment: This example from the JVM workshop is what I was referring to: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-jvm-spring#step-8---authorization. If you're getting a 404, that would indicate that the request in the pact file does not match any actual path on your provider. I'd really recommend joining slack.pact.io and fleshing it out there, this set of comments is not going to be easy to follow for others.